# How to destroy session in jsp and avoid returning back

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, session, servlets

I'm doing a web site this website has a login and profile when I click on logout I redirected to the home page but when I press back button in the browser I returned to the account which should not be accessed because disconnected from it, I tried all possibilities with : `session.invalidate();` and others like for js with localstorage and the same thing keep happening. please help me as soon as possible.

```
<% 
    if (session.getAttribute("userid") != null) { 
        session.invalidate();
        response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
        return;
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

I can't comment but I can share what I've used back in the past and it worked like a charm.

[Try this Disable browser back button](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/04/disable-browser-back-button-javascript.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like set back your `session attribute` to null

```
if (session.getAttribute("userid") != null) {
    session.setAttribute("emp_code", null);
    session.setAttribute("emp_name", null);
    session.setAttribute("emp_desig", null);
    session.setAttribute("emp_plant", null);

    session.invalidate();
    response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
    return;
}
```